# Find all the possible scores on a quiz

Tags: algorithms

I'm using Typeform to create a personality quiz. The way it works is that I have to give each answer (A,B,C,D) a score (1,10,100,1000).

| Option | Score |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 10 |
| C | 100 |
| D | 1000 |

If I have a 5 question quiz, and a user selects all `A`s, their score will be a `5`.
If a user selects 4 `A`s and a `B` their score will be `14`, and I know I can show them the screen for majority `A`.
If a user selects 1 `A` 1 `B` and 3 `C`s the score will be `311`. In this case, the majority will be `C`.

I need to set up the quiz so that if the results are over `311`, it shows the screen for C, and so on.

This is the way they build their quizzes (see their Avanced Personality Test docs [here](https://help.typeform.com/hc/en-us/articles/360029583071-Create-a-personality-quiz-Classic-builder-)), it is a lot of work to come up with all the combinations manually (their example is for a 4 question quiz).

But what's the best way to get all the possible score which I need to manually input on Typeform? I don't need to know which option has the majority of votes, but I need to find every possible sum of scores.

I had originally asked this question Stack Overflow but perhaps this is a better place to ask this.

Answer (score 1):

If you have $N$ answers and there are $R$ possible answers to each question you are looking for weak compositions of $N$ out of $R$ pieces.  These are all the ordered ways to have $R$ whole numbers (including $0$) that sum to $N$.  You can do this with [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).  Add $1$ to each piece so you are looking for compositions of $N+R$ out of $R$ pieces, each of which must be at least $1$.  Imagine $N+R$ stars in a row.  Choose $R-1$ of the places between them to place bars.  There are ${N+R-1 \choose R-1}$ ways to do this.  List them and compute the score for each.

In your example, you have $N=5, R=4$.  The composition $9=2+2+4+2$ corresponds to $2-1=1\ A, 1\ B, \ 3\ Cs, 1\ D$ and gives your score of $311$.  The composition $9=4+3+1+1$ would correspond to $3\ As, 2\ Bs$ and a score of $23$